# Subscribe on values change in url angular

Tags: angular

I have url like this

```
www.test.com?state=da#value=1&test=2
```

When I want to subscribe on changes in url, i have tried like this

```
this.route.params.subscribe(() => {
      this.urlParams = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('state');
      this.urlFragment = this.route.snapshot.fragment;
      if (!this.urlParams) {
        this.router.navigate([`/error/401`]);
      }
});
```

It is fine because I can check if something changed in **state** params and value is changed, but if something changed in **value** like **value=2** url fragment is not changed??

I know i can do like

```
this.route.fragment.subscribe();
```

This way i have two subscription, i want to subscribe to any change in url? Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **combineLatest** from **rxjs** fro your subscriptions, something like this:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
combineLatest(this.route.params, this.route.fragment).pipe(
  map(([params, fragment]) => console.log(params + '' + fragment) )
).subscribe()
```

Comment: combineLatest is deprecated

Comment: which version of rxjs are you using